# How can you left justify list items in a unordered list that is centered within a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div within a div within a div:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="center">
    <div id="content" class="center">
        <div id="listDiv" class="center">
           <ul>
               <li><a href='#' id="1" >Link one</a> </li>
               <li><a href='#' id="2" >Link 2</a> </li>
               <li><a href='#' id="3" >Link three</a> </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my style sheet, I have a class that centers each div within the page, and centers things within the div:

```
div.center{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I would like my unordered list to remain centered in the div, but for each list item to be left justified below the other.  Everything I have tried centers the list items to each other.  What am I missing?

Comment: use text-align:left style for the li's

Answer (score 21, accepted):

May be, you want this. **[SEE THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hCQS2/1)**

To achieve what you want, you have to give `display: table;` to your div.

```
div.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: table;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just add

```
ul {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your list is inheriting the `text-align: center;`, so try setting the `div.listDiv` or `div.listDiv ul` to `text-align: left;`.

I believe this should solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
#listDiv.ul {
    text-align: left;
}
```

This will left-align the text in any `UL` that is contained within a div with ID of **`listDiv`**.

If you just type the following:

```
ul {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Then you will left-align the text of EVERY `UL` everywhere.